# Google map - Multiple marker

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to set multiple markers, getting address fetching from database and storing it to javascript array variable, then by running a loop trying to set markers in my map, but its not working.

This is my working URL : http://projects.pronixtech.net/kindcampaign/kind-country/

Please look to the source code, and please guys help me i have already given my full day on this.

Comment: how many marker want to display? I have seen 9 markers

Comment: can you please post the source code here.. Else this question wuld invaluable to someone else.. Also host a jsfiddle for the same..

Comment: @pratik I want to display more than 150 markers.

Comment: @zzz can you please tell me what's jsfiddle is?

Comment: normally people google.. :P but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68467/make-askers-aware-of-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

FYI There is a JS error on your page i.e it could not find `$(".videopan")` i guess and you need not do the replace of px etc for parsing you could do

```
parseInt($(".videopan").css("left"))
```

i.e

```
parseInt("50px")=50
```